# embedding a page with some javascript on a tumblr post

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I want to reproduce a simple, one page website with some javascript in a tumblr post (as a form of documentation for a project) but everytime I try to put the source html of the site into the tumblr form it ends up not loading at all inside the tumblr... Here's the page I'm trying to "embed" into tumblr: www.benenson.ae/recording.html

When I copy the html into the tumblr console, I'm fixing the path to the scripts at the top so that's not the problem..Am I missing some trick for getting this to work inside Tumblr?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure what support there was for iframes in tumblr, but it is possible, but you will need to add some styling to suit your needs:

I simply created a new post, selected the html tab and then put in the following code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.benenson.ae/recording.html"></iframe>
```

Alternatively you could create a single post, uploading the image content to tumblr and make it link to anywhere you like, and then add a caption for the post that replicates the current text you have.

If that helps or you want to pursue the second option, let me know and I can update my answer.

Comment: OK so you have scripts running on that page, so creating a single post is more tricky. I think it would be possible but you would have to link to any hosted scripts and use absolute urls.